# Dispose array of string in a loop

Tags: c#, arrays, garbage-collection, dispose

I have the following loop inside a function:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 46;i++){
    String[] arrStr = File.ReadAllLines(path+"File_"+i+".txt")
    List<String> output = new List<String>();
    for(j = 0;j< arrStr.Length;j++){
       //Do Something
        output.Add(someString);
    }
    File.WriteAllLines(path+"output_File_"+i+".txt",output.toArray());
    output.Clear();
}
```

Each txt file has about 20k lines.The function opens 46 of them and I need to run the function more than 1k times so I'm planning to leave the program running overnight,so far I didnt find any erros but since there is an 20k size String array being referenced at each interaction of the loop,i'm afraid that there might be some issue with trash memory being acumulated or something from the arrays in the past interactions. If there is such a risk,which method is best to dispose of the old array in this case?
Also,is it memory safe to run 3 programs like this at the same time?

Comment: You can optimize this a little with `List<String> output = new List<String>(arrStr.Length);` . But there are no issues. Running 3 at a time will probably be slower than sequential, measure.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Streams` with `using` this will handle the memory management for you:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 46; i++)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputpath))
        {
            while(!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                // do something with line
                writer.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Dispose` methods of `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` are automatically called when exiting the `using` block, freeing up any memory used. Using streams also ensures your entire file isn't in memory at once.

More info on [MSDN - File Stream and I/O](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3352a4t(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you came from the C world :-) 
C# garbage collection is fine, you will not have any problems with that.

I would be more worried about file-system errors.